# VTK Data does not appear in CellData or PointData (numpy interface)

Tags: python, vtk

I have a VTK file that correctly populates the data in ParaView:

[image]

However, when I open that same file with VTK's Python API, I cannot for the life of me seem to find these same labeled datasets. Here's what I've tried:

```
import vtk
from vtk.numpy_interface import dataset_adapter as dsa

reader = vtk.vtkUnstructuredGridReader()
reader.SetFileName('test.vtk')
reader.Update()

adapter = dsa.WrapDataObject(reader.GetOutput())
print(adapter.PointData.keys()) # ['hu', 'disp']
print(adapter.CellData.keys())  # []
print(adapter.FieldData.keys()) # []
```

So, it seems that ParaView is able to identify the other datasets beyond just 'hu' and 'disp', but I cannot seem to find them in the corresponding Python object.

I'm assuming it's there somewhere. Anyone know why they, e.g., 'meanstress', don't appear as keys?

Comment: I would attach the file but it's 574MB

Comment: Can you reproduce with smaller dataset ? If you remove some of the arrays for example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ask the reader to read all the data.

```
reader.ReadAllScalarsOn()
reader.ReadAllVectorsOn()
...
```

Dependending of wich kind  of data you are trying to load. 
(scalars, vector, tensor ... See for the whole list: https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkDataReader.html#a831f470c6fbfc6e7209a1243ccb546e2 )